# HDinsight - Hive Java Heap Error

Tags: mapreduce, hive, azure-hdinsight

I'm trying to run a simple query with Hive on HDinsight.
A map task keeps failing, below is the log error:

```
2015-02-28 19:01:02,114 INFO [main]       org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper: ExecMapper: processed 336785 rows: used memory = 414394136
2015-02-28 19:01:02,130 FATAL [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Error running child : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I tried to set java heap size by adding:
    set mapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx2048m;

I also tried to set this value to -Xmx1024m up to -Xmx8g with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I had a dataset problem, one row in my file was near 5gb